# How can I count the number of projects without record id?

Tags: sql

I am kind of new to sql. I would appreciate your help.
I have a project table( multiple projects), and I have field table.
Theoretically, each project table has some fields/questions from the field table.
I am trying to find all the projects that does not have record id.

I have tried to use this query, but it is not working.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT PROJECT.PROJECTID), PROJECT.PROJECTID
FROM PROJECT
 JOIN  FIELD
ON PROJECT.PROJECTID = FIELD.PROJECTID
WHERE FIELD.PROJECT-HAS-RECORD !=1
GROUP BY PROJECT.PROJECTID;
```

[image]

The expected result should be :
[image]

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: Could you please add your expected result?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You are counting the **`DISTINCT`** values of `PROJECT.PROJECTID` for each distinct group of `PROJECT.PROJECTID`; that `COUNT` can *only* return 1 of two values: `1` (when `PROJECT.PROJECTID` isn't `NULL`) or `0` (when `PROJECT.PROJECTID` is `NULL`).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you're doing a COUNT if you're looking for project IDs...

Making some guesses and assumptions, but something like this might get you closer:

```
select
    p.projectid
from 
    project p
    join
    field f on f.projectid = p.projectid
where
    f.fieldid = 'field1'
    and
    f.project-has-field = 0
```